# How calculate the probability when we have continuous features?

Tags: bayesian

Suppose that we have a dataset with four features and each feature follows different distribution (normal,beta,gamma...). All features are continuous. So, how we can calculate the probability of any target if we want to follow Bayesian rule? ( Because the probability will be zero for each). We can imagine the iris dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a side by side comparison between discrete and continuous Naive Bayes:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47027/how-does-naive-bayes-classifier-work-for-continuous-variables/47031#47031

Comment: Yes, also this was helpful: https://youtu.be/H3EjCKtlVog

Answer (score 0):

If you have discrete features, you can multiply each probability. But if you have continuous features, first you need to estimate the distribution and then instead of multiplying probabilities, you should multiply likelihoods.
For more info please watch the videos from statquest on youtube.
Gaussian Naive Bayes